# The parent of <img> returns <source> instead of <picture>

Tags: php, image, domdocument

```
$content = '<picture>
    <source type="image/avif" srcset="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/image.avif 800w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/image-350x200.avif 350w, https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/image-150x150.avif 150w">
    <img src="https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/image.jpg">
</picture>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$content = utf8_decode($content);
$doc->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
// The problem is here
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->parentNode->tagName;
```

Why does it echo `source` instead of `picture`? Isn't `picture` the parent of `img`?

Comment: Your `<source>` tag isn't closed, not totally sure here but I know in some contexts that will be interpreted as containing its successor siblings

Comment: Yeah, you are right. The closing tag fixed it. Thank you. `<source ...></source>`  OR  `<source />`